# Communication between components in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I know, that communication between components in Vuejs >= 2.0 is done by three concepts

1. **props** - is how outer context can pass data to the component,
2. **events** - is how component lets know outer context about changes,
3. **slots** - this one is not important for my question.

I am also aware of central state pattern and all that stuff around it. But sometimes is common to be able to tell to child component "do something, what changes your **internal state**".

Here are some scenarios:

1. TreeView (recursive component) and "collapse all" button - you need to tell all child components to collapse. I know, here is applicable central state pattern, but let's imagine that state of the node (expanded/collapsed) is part of component's internal state.
2. Counters - i can have multiple counters on the page a parent component have button "increment all" - again, I need to "call" increment method on each child component.

Question is: how to achieve "event based" communication between components in parent -> children direction. I feel that it's kinda common scenario.

I made an example jsbin. However, I'm not sure it doesn't violate some fundamental ideas of vue js.

https://jsbin.com/kakucuf/edit?html,js,output

```
const Foo = {
  name: 'Foo',
  template: '#a-template',
  props: {
    name: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$on('increment', this.increment);
  },

  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.counter += 1;
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  components: {
    foo: Foo,
  },
  methods: {
    incrementAll() {
      this.$children.forEach((child) => child.$emit('increment'));
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [computed properties and watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad) would make the job for you.

In your parent component, you can use computed properties as props for child components. As soon as computed properties do change, your child component is updated thanks to Vue.js reactive functionalities.

And, in your child component, use watchers to keep control over changes from this component context.

Starting from your scenarios:

1. you could use a `collapse` prop on your parent component, and "listen" (or actually "watch") for its value change through a watcher in your child component, the watcher function will do the job of collapsing within each of the children components if the new value is `true`
2. your could send a `increment` prop from your parent component, and watch for its value change through a watcher in your child component

As an example, for the second scenario, use an `increment` prop from your parent component, and watch it in your child component like that:

```
watch: {
    increment: function (newVal) {
        if (newVal === true) {
            this.counter++
        }
    }
}
```

Within your parent component, setting `this.increment` to `true` will trigger the watcher in your children components. If you need to increment more, be aware you'll have to set it back to another value like `null` before re-assigning `true`.

That's kind of a hack, and should stand for the time when you start considering state management solutions like [Vuex](http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html)!

Comment: What you advise is "central state" pattern. This way I am forced to lift state one (or more) level higher. But it's sometimes impossible. But yea it's definitely the way. I am just asking if there is a way to violate (for good reasons) this rule and if so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. What you call "central state" for me is Vuex or alternatives (like a `bus` instance...). Using a watcher in your deeper level component allow you to know when data from props has changed, and to run some code each time it changes.

Comment: Maybe I am getting it wrong. Would you be so kind and scatch it for me here: https://jsbin.com/kahaba/1/edit?html,js,output?

Comment: Yeah, this is hacky :) and for me kinda similar to what I did with events ... To be clear, I am using Vuex. But I want to have a (reusable) TreeView component, it's data will of course come from Vuex state. But exactly that collapse/expand feature of a tree is what I don't want to have in central state (especially when I will have multiple instances of this component at once) - maybe there is no reason to be afraid to put this in central state, but after that the treeview component will be completely dump - all it's logic will depend on Vuex store. I am confused :(.

Comment: Actually, you are looking at `$dispatch` and `$broadcast`! But it's [not anymore in Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced). Evan himself recommend using Vuex to make your application _"more maintainable"_, and he is fù€kin' genious! So maybe you shouldn't be afraid to use Vuex :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134780/discussion-between-jakub-trunecek-and-clorichel).